# Undefined reference to "tf2::fromMsg()"

Tags: ros, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have saw [link](https://answers.ros.org/question/273775/undefined-reference-to-tf2frommsg/) and [link text](https://answers.ros.org/question/267657/tf2frommsg-cause-undefined-reference/) , but both cant solve my problem.

The error msg is follow

> e(geometry_msgs::Pose_std::allocator<void >)':
> /home/bot/chh_ros_ws/src/car_navigation/navigation/car_motion_ctrl/src/ctrl_node.cpp:31: undefined reference to `void tf2::fromMsg<geometry_msgs::Pose_std::allocator<void >, tf2::Quaternion>(geometry_msgs::Pose_std::allocator<void > const&, tf2::Quaternion&)'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make[2]: *** [car_navigation/navigation/car_motion_ctrl/CMakeFiles/ctrlNode.dir/build.make:107: /home/bot/chh_ros_ws/devel/lib/car_motion_ctrl/ctrlNode] Error 1
> make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2583: car_navigation/navigation/car_motion_ctrl/CMakeFiles/ctrlNode.dir/all] Error 2
> make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
> Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed

I has follow [Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Quaternions#CA-bc2dd80473f30260c2655ce51f9d8c4332ad4bd3_1) to do and include correct file.

Here is my code

```
#include "motion_controller.h"
#include <nav_msgs/Path.h>
#include "dwa_planner.h"
#include <tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h>

    bool rec_flag = 0;
    Pose_t cur_pose;

    void path_pubRECV(const nav_msgs::Path::ConstPtr msg, std::vector<Pose_t> *path)
    {
            rec_flag = true;
            Pose_t pt;
            for(int i=0; i<msg->poses.size()-1; ++i) {
                pt.x = msg->poses[i].pose.position.x;
                pt.y = msg->poses[i].pose.position.y;
                pt.yaw = atan((pt.y - msg->poses[i+1].pose.position.y)/
                            (pt.x - msg->poses[i+1].pose.position.x));
                path->push_back(pt);
            }

            pt.x = msg->poses.back().pose.position.x;
            pt.y = msg->poses.back().pose.position.y;
            pt.yaw = cur_pose.yaw;
            path->push_back(pt);
    }

    void UpdatePose(const geometry_msgs::Pose msg) {
            tf2::Quaternion quat_tf;
            tf2::fromMsg(msg, quat_tf);
            cur_pose.x = msg.position.x;
            cur_pose.y = msg.position.y;
            cur_pose.yaw = quat_tf.getAngleShortestPath();
    }



    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
            ros::init(argc, argv, "ctrl_node");
            ros::NodeHandle n;

            string PathName = argv[1]; 

            std::vector<Pose_t> global_path;
            ros::Subscriber path_sub = n.subscribe<nav_msgs::Path>(PathName, 1, boost::bind(&path_pubRECV, _1, &global_path));
            ros::Subscriber pos_sub = n.subscribe("car_position", 1, UpdatePose);

        .......and so on
```

cmake_list is
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(car_motion_ctrl)
# SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    geometry_msgs
    nav_msgs
    roscpp
    rospy
    std_msgs
    tf2
    tf2_ros
    tf2_geometry_msgs
)

catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES car_motion_ctrl
 CATKIN_DEPENDS geometry_msgs nav_msgs roscpp rospy tf2 tf2_ros
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
# include
    include/car_motionCtrl
    include/local_planner
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(ctrlNode src/ctrl_node.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ctrlNode ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

package.xml is here

```
<package format="2">
    <name>car_motion_ctrl</name>
    <version>0.0.0</version>
    <description>The car_motion_ctrl package</description>

    <maintainer email="heho@todo.todo">heho</maintainer>

    <license>TODO</license>

    <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
    <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
    <build_export_depend>geometry_msgs</build_export_depend>
    <exec_depend>geometry_msgs</exec_depend>
    <build_depend>tf2_geometry_msgs</build_depend>
    <build_export_depend>tf2_geometry_msgs</build_export_depend>
    <exec_depend>tf2_geometry_msgs</exec_depend>
    <build_depend>nav_msgs</build_depend>
    <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
    <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
    <build_export_depend>nav_msgs</build_export_depend>
    <build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>
    <build_export_depend>rospy</build_export_depend>
    <exec_depend>nav_msgs</exec_depend>
    <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
    <exec_depend>rospy</exec_depend>
    <build_depend>tf2</build_depend>
    <build_export_depend>tf2</build_export_depend>
    <exec_depend>tf2</exec_depend>
    <build_depend>tf2_ros</build_depend>
    <build_export_depend>tf2_ros</build_export_depend>
    <exec_depend>tf2_ros</exec_depend>

    <export>
    </export>
</package>
```

And I should have install tf2 package, when I enter 'ls /opt/ros/noetic/lib/ | grep tf2', I got

> libtf2_ros.so
> libtf2.so
> tf2_kdl
> tf2_ros
> turtle_tf2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399421/undefined-reference-to-%22tf2::frommsg()%22/) by [Heho](https://answers.ros.org/users/52976/heho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 44 on 2022-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to pass just the orientation object, not the entire Pose message.

The c++ prototype in `tf2_geometry_msgs.h` is:

```
void fromMsg(const geometry_msgs::Quaternion& in, tf2::Quaternion& out)
```

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Heho](https://answers.ros.org/users/52976/heho/) on 2022-04-23**:
It works! But, why? I can find another overload in `tf2_geometry_msgs.h` in line 440 --- `void fromMsg(const geometry_msgs::Pose& in, tf2::Transform& out)`.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-04-23**:
That doesn't work because a `tf2:Quaternion` is not a `tf2:Transform`.

**Comment by [Heho](https://answers.ros.org/users/52976/heho/) on 2022-04-23**:
Oh! The editor didn't report this unmatch parameter and I ignore this... Thanks!